# contour integral with a singularity of a fractional power

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, complex-integration

Let $C$ be a simple closed positively oriented contour, and suppose $f$ is complex analytic both within and on $C$. Assume that the origin lies inside $C$.
How deal with contour integrals of the form
$$ \int_{C} \frac{f(z)}{z^\frac{1}{m}}dz,\qquad m\in \mathbb{N}.$$

Motivation: I need to solve the following integral
$$ \int_{C_1} \frac{e^{-z^2}}{(z-\dot{\imath} t)^\frac{1}{3}}dz,\qquad t\in \mathbb{R}.$$

Obviously, I am interested in the case where $t$ lies in the domain $C_1$ encloses.

Comment: There's no such thing as a pole of fractional degree. Before you can evaluate the first integral you need to decide which of the various possible values of $z^{1/m}$ you're going to consider.

Comment: Thanks. I edited the title.